# 500 Server Error with data transfer in API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api

```
public APIController()
{
    db = new ApplicationDbContext();
}

ApplicationDbContext db;
[HttpGet]
public List<Category> GetCategories()s
{
    return db.Categories.ToList();
}
```

I am trying to get categories from the Web API. I am using AJAX, but it gives a 500 exception.

Comment: A 500 error may be logging something to the event log; open up the Event Viewer and look in the Application log and see if something is recorded.  Is the connection string setup correctly?  Are other database calls working?

Comment: Connection string setups are correct. i tried it on mvc controller, and database call worked. It doesnt work only for api

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15262337

Answer (score 0):

Since connection string is right and all setup correctly, There are 2 possible issues in the code I see:

1- Your Api Controller is named APIController which is a reserved word in .NET Api

2- Your get service is trying to return a complete Object from categories which might be related to parent objects and the parent objects are related to other related objects which results in returning the whole database.

I suggest using `select new` in lambda like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<Category> GetCategories()s
{
    return db.Categories.Select(a => new { a.Name, a.ID, a.Description }).ToList();
}
```

This way you avoid querying the whole database.